# how to access properties of an object which is property of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have this

```
Object { name: "Fresh", styleUrl: "#icon-959-F8971B-nodesc", ExtendedData: "", Point: Object }
```

and there is another property in the last one (Point:Object) like

```
coordinate:"1,2,3"
```

I want to access to the string "1,2,3" and separate it to variable like

```
x=1,y=2
```

I don't need 3 .Do you have any idea for javascript?

Comment: `obj.obj2.obj3.obj4.prop` ...?

Comment: Not clear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: `Object.Point.coordinate`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the coordinate string via [dot-notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/) like so:

```
var theObject; // your Object { name: "Fresh", styleUrl: "#icon-959-F8971B-nodesc", ExtendedData: "", Point: Object }
var coordinate = theObject.Point.coordinate;
```

and if you want to convert it from a `String` into an object with `x` and `y` properties you can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it into an `Array` and extract the values like so:

```
var points = coordinate.split(',');
var x = points[0];
var y = points[1];

var coordinatePoint = {
    x: x,
    y: y
};
```

and access the `x`/`y` values like so:

```
console.log(coordinatePoint.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I does not matter how many nested objects there are, you can just access them normally with the `.` notation or with `[]`.

For example with your data:

```
var obj = { name: "Fresh", styleUrl: "#icon-959-F8971B-nodesc", ExtendedData: "", Point: {"coordinate":"1,2,3"} };

var coord = obj.Point.coordinate;

var array = coord.split(',');

// for example, get the second value, at index 1 since we start from 0
console.log(array[1]);
```

prints to the console:

```
2
```